# Unable to find Torch header files using nvcc

Tags: compilation, cuda, nvcc, luajit, torch

I'm trying to call some CUDA code from luaJIT (Torch) but I'm running into compiling issues. nvcc seems unable to find my Torch header files. I have CUDA 6.5 and gcc 4.4.7.

```
nvcc -o im2col -I/deep/u/ibello/torch/include im2col.cu    
In file included from /deep/u/ibello/torch/include/THC/THC.h:4,
                     from utils.h:6,
                     from im2col.cu:1:
    /deep/u/ibello/torch/include/THC/THCGeneral.h:4:23: error: THGeneral.h: No such file or directory
    /deep/u/ibello/torch/include/THC/THCGeneral.h:5:25: error: THAllocator.h: No such file or directory
    In file included from /deep/u/ibello/torch/include/THC/THC.h:7,
                     from utils.h:6,
                     from im2col.cu:1:
    /deep/u/ibello/torch/include/THC/THCStorage.h:4:23: error: THStorage.h: No such file or directory
    In file included from /deep/u/ibello/torch/include/THC/THC.h:9,
                     from utils.h:6,
                     from im2col.cu:1:
```

im2col.cu includes the following

```
#include "utils.h"
#include "common.h"
#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <lualib.h>
```

where "utils.h" is

```
#ifndef CUNN_UTILS_H
#define CUNN_UTILS_H

extern "C" { #include <lua.h> }
#include <luaT.h>
#include <THC/THC.h>

THCState* getCutorchState(lua_State* L);

#endif
```

This is relatively weird since the mentioned files are indeed in the include location I gave to the compiler..

```
ls /deep/u/ibello/torch/include/THC
THCAllocator.h  THCDeviceTensor.cuh       THCDeviceTensorUtils-inl.cuh  THC.h                    THCReduce.cuh     THCTensorConv.h  THCTensorMath.h
THCApply.cuh    THCDeviceTensor-inl.cuh   THCDeviceUtils.cuh            THCReduceAll.cuh         THCStorageCopy.h  THCTensorCopy.h  THCTensorRandom.h
THCBlas.h       THCDeviceTensorUtils.cuh  THCGeneral.h                  THCReduceApplyUtils.cuh  THCStorage.h      THCTensor.h      THCTensorSort.h
```

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

Thx in advance!

Comment: It's looking for `THGeneral.h` and you have shown where `THCGeneral.h` is.  Those are not the same file.  Perhaps you also need to include the path to where `THGeneral.h` and other files like that are: `-I/deep/u/ibello/torch/path/to/THGeneral.h`

Comment: That was the problem thx! THGeneral.h was in subdirectory of the path I provided tho, so not sure why that wasn't working..

Comment: compilers don't search all subdirectories of the path you provide.  They only search the directory that you provide.

Comment: The THC files were in ..../torch/include/THC while the TH files were in ..../torch/include/TH. Here the compiler was able to find the THC files but not the TH ones (which are #included from the THC ones). So the compiler was at least able to search the THC subdirectory

Comment: The compiler found its way into `.../include/THC` when you specified `-I/deep/u/ibello/torch/include` because of this construct: `#include <THC/THC.h>`  Once it was "in that directory", other files included from `THC.h` may be discoverable *in that directory that THC.h is in*.   You can see a hint of this if you read your posting carefully.   None of these mechanisms, however, allow it to discover files in `.../include/TH` unless you either point it there, or the include file has a partial path specified, like `#include "../TH/THGeneral.h"`

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this compile command:

```
nvcc -o im2col -I/deep/u/ibello/torch/include im2col.cu
```

did not give the necessary search paths for the compiler to find the header files like `THGeneral.h` that were located in `/deep/u/ibello/torch/include/TH`

The solution was to specify a compile command like this:

```
nvcc -o im2col -I/deep/u/ibello/torch/include -I/deep/u/ibello/torch/include/TH im2col.cu
```